# Can I connect a Google Apps Script program to the external Tesseract OCR software for a more robust OCR?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, ocr, tesseract

Can I connect an Google Apps Script program with the OCR software called Tesseract OCR? I would like to know because Google sponsors the Tesseract OCR project - https://opensource.google/projects/tesseract

I need the software to convert tabular information stored in a pdf file into a editable text which the standard OCR cannot achieve.

Comment: GAS does not natively support Tesseract (its written in C++ after all). But you can try looking for a javascript port of the library. If you find one that works with GAS let us know.

Comment: There is a Javascript port of the Tesseract. I'm relatively new to AppScript so I don't know if the port is useable in GAS. 

https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/